# I can't get nodes to work, wondering if it's a glitch or I'm doing something wrong

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes

I can get nodes in Blender to display the image/movie clip I'm trying to display in the backdrop and it plays when I press the play button, but there's no sound and it doesn't display in the preview. I tried putting multiple types of viewers at the end of the sequence of nodes and even tried putting only one movie clip into the node editor, and attaching it to the view node. Still didn't make a difference. Does anybody know if this is just a glitch or is there something I'm doing wrong? (My blender version is 2.8.1, if that helps) After about a day of trying to work it out, I am still having the same issue, and even after re-adding in the "Render Layers" and "Composite" nodes, the render doesn't show the composite, it only shows the video-editing preview. (Edit: I solved it, I just forgot to attach the final image to composite as opposed to having render layers attached to composite.)

Comment: Hello :). I'm glad you solved it by yourself. Please post your solution as an answer, for others with the same problem. Thank you and have a great day.